# how to solve a weighted completion time minimization problem to cplex/c++?

Tags: c++, optimization, time, cplex, completion

[a scheduling problem that wants to minimize a weighted completion time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq8aA.jpg)

I would like to pass the image problem to the c++ language and solve it with cplex solver.

Problem:

Min ∑WiCi

xi ∈ 0,1

t= ∆ + ∑_{i} xi*pi1

Ci1 = ∑_{j=1}^{i} xj*pj1

Ci2 = t + ∑_{j=1}^{i} (1−xj)*pj2

Ci ≥ Ci1

Ci ≥ Ci2−Ωxi

Ω = ∆ + ∑_i max(pi1, pi2)

The goal is to minimize the weighted completion time of a problem with one machine with at most one machine reconfiguration. I have a boolean variable Xi that tells me if the job is done before or after the reconfiguration. The variable t is the instant after the reconfiguration(delta is the time to reconfigure the machine). pi1 is the processing time in configuration 1 and pi2 is the processing time in configuration 2. Besides, I have restrictions due to Ci (completion time of a job i).
The example of code I made is not working. I know I have a problem writing the C variable (but I don't know how to solve it).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <ilcp/cp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int nbJob = 4;
    int delta = 2;
    int nbConf = 2;
    vector<int> w_job;
    w_job.push_back(1); w_job.push_back(1); w_job.push_back(1); w_job.push_back(1); 
    
    vector<vector<int>>p_job;
    p_job.resize(nbJob);
    p_job[0].push_back(6); p_job[0].push_back(3); 
    p_job[1].push_back(1); p_job[1].push_back(2); 
    p_job[2].push_back(10); p_job[2].push_back(2);
    p_job[3].push_back(1); p_job[3].push_back(9); 
    
    int max_p = 0;
    int aux;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob - 1; i++) {
            aux = max(p_job[i][0], p_job[i][1]);
            max_p = max(max_p, aux);
    }
    cout << max_p << endl;

    int max_w = 0;
    aux = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob - 1; i++) {
        aux = max(w_job[i], w_job[i + 1]);
        max_w = max(aux, max_w);
    }
    cout << max_w << endl;

    int omega = 0; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
        omega += max(p_job[i][0], p_job[i][1]);
    }
    omega += delta;
    cout << omega << endl;
   

    try {
        IloEnv env; 
        IloModel model(env); 

        IloBoolVarArray x(env, nbJob);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            IloBoolVar xi(env, 0, 1, "xi");
            x[i] = xi;
        }
        
        
                
        IloArray<IloExprArray> C(env, nbJob); 
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) { 
            IloExprArray Ci(env);
            for (size_t j = 0; j < nbConf; j++) { 
                IloExpr  Cij(env);
                Ci.add(Cij);
            }
            C[i] = Ci;
        }
        

        IloNumVarArray C_final(env, nbJob);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            IloNumVar C_finali(env, 0, IloInfinity, ILOINT); //
            C_final[i] = C_finali;
        }

        
        

        IloExpr t(env);
        for (int i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            t += x[i] * p_job[i][0];
        }
        t += delta;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < nbJob; j++) {
                if (j <= i) {
                    C[i][0] += x[j] * p_job[j][0];
                    
                }
            }
        }



        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < nbJob; j++) {
                if (j <= i) {
                    C[i][1] += ((1 - x[j]) * p_job[j][1]);
                }
            }
            C[i][1] += t;
        }
        



        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            model.add(C_final[i] >= C[i][0]);
        }
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            model.add(C_final[i] >= C[i][1] - (omega * x[i]));
        }
           


        IloExpr wiCi(env);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            wiCi += w_job[i] * C_final[i];
        }
        

        model.add(IloMinimize(env, wiCi)); 
        

        IloCplex solver(model);
        

        solver.solve();

        for (int i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            cout << "C " << i + 1 << " = " << solver.getValue(C_final[i]) << "  x" << i+1 << " = " << solver.getValue(x[i]) << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "t = " << solver.getValue(t) << endl;

        cout << "wiCi = " << solver.getObjValue() << endl << endl;
    }
    catch (IloException e) {
        cout << e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way it is not working? Do you have some expected results and bad results to compare?

Comment: I think I have a problem with the "+=". the program is giving as result:
C 1 = 10
C 2 = 0
C 3 = 0
C 4 = 0
C 5 = 0
wiCi = 10. it's not sorting the data

Comment: I found some problems and I fixed the code that is in the question. Now, it doesn't order exactly as it should. The values given in the code it gives me as the answer: C 1 = 9 ; C 2 = 2 ; C 3 = 7 ; C 4 = 1 ; wiCi = 19. But the good answer is: C 1 = 6 ; C 2 = 2 ; C 3 = 9 ; C 4 = 1 ; wiCi = 18.

Comment: If you know a good answer, try forcing that answer on your problem model - something like model.Add(C1 = 9) and so on. Then you should either find that solution is OK or more likely you will find it infeasible and can then start checking which constraint(s) are wrong by e.g. commenting out one or more constraints or parts of the constraints.

Comment: I found my problem, but I still can't solve it: 

for (size_t i = 0; i < nbJob; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < nbJob; j++) {
                if (j <= i) {
                    C[i][0] += x[j] * p_job[j][0];
                    
                }
            }
        }
The problem is that it only tells which configuration each job has to be in, without sorting the right order